# UrbanAirShip integrated in my project. its not working well in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I created a new `urbanairship` account and i followed all the documentation stated on [their link](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios/?swift#sdk-installation) but when i setup the `AppDelegate` part as they mentioned:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let config = UAConfig.default();
    UAirship.takeOff(config);
    UAirship.push().defaultPresentationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UAirship.push().userPushNotificationsEnabled = true;
    return true;
}
```

my code crashes on `UAirship.push().defaultPresentationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]` saying: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.`

I debugged and found out that `UAirship.push()` is resulting in a nil.

Also note that i have created the `AirshipConfig.pList` file as requested on the same page and i have pasted the following:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>developmentAppKey</key>
    <string>Your Development App Key</string>
    <key>developmentAppSecret</key>
    <string>Your Development App Secret</string>
    <key>productionAppKey</key>
    <string>Your Production App Key</string>
    <key>productionAppSecret</key>
    <string>Your Production App Secret</string>
    <key>useWKWebView</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Can somebody tell me what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you replaced the `Your Development App ...` placeholder text with your actual app Keys and Secrets? (don't paste them here - just confirm)

Comment: thanks for replying, no i havent, I really dont know where to get that from, can you please tell me.

Comment: Did you follow everything here: https://docs.urbanairship.com/engage/getting-started/  and did you download their sample iOS Swift app?

Comment: UAirship singleton will be nil if its not set up right. Follow what @DonMag suggested and you should be good to go.

Comment: Note: Airship's onboarding process has a UX bug (as of May 16, 2019). You view the app Keys and Secret until you finish the "Getting started" tutorial, but you need these to successfully send a push notification, which is the last step. To get around this just tap the send pushbutton and click the "I received the notificaiton" checkbox. You will then be able to access the dashboard where you can view the keys in Setting>APIs & Integrations

Answer (score 1):

useWKWebView seems to be long invalid:

> 2018-12-11 15:32:10.228876+0300 V4 P97 Dev[4468:2691527] [D]
>   -[UAConfig setValue:forUndefinedKey:] [Line 404] Ignoring invalid UAConfig key: useWKWebView

probably it's on by default though you can't tell by the size of the font
inside that `WKWebView` ;^)